# use of particles on direct object

Tags: particle-が, particle-を, nouns, transitivity

When is the use of correct particle (を or が) on the direct object of a transitive verb, for example:

- shigoto o owarimasu
- shigoto ga owarimasu

What is the exact meaning in each other, please.

Comment: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/609/the-difference-between-%E3%81%8C-and-%E3%82%92-with-the-potential-form-of-a-verb?rq=1

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka ごめんなさいやっぱり関係している気がしてきました

Comment: @naruto, I don't mind except learner gets the right answers.

Answer (score 6):

Many Japanese verbs [have transitive and intransitive versions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14861/5010). Basically, 終わる (owaru) is an **intransitive** verb. 終える (oeru) is the transitive equivalent. So here are the most basic usages:

> - 仕事が終わります。 Shigoto ga owarimasu. (**intransitive**)
>     The task finishes.
> - 仕事を終えます。 Shigoto o oemasu. (**transitive**)
>     I finish the task.

In plain and active sentences like your example, the direct object of a transitive verb is always marked with を. In potential and passive sentences there are a lot more to know.

- Potential: [The difference between が and を with the potential form of a verb.](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/609/5010)
- Passive: [Passive form - The exact difference between を and が](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11025/5010)

So, these are the generic rules.

But in case you have seen ～を終わる before, please read on.

---

However, 終わる (owaru) happens to have an exceptional transitive usage, too. See: [When is 終わる used as a transitive verb?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5043/5010) It's the fourth definition of [this dictionary entry](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/34223/meaning/m0u/%E7%B5%82%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8B/).

> - 今日の授業**を**終わります。
>     That's all for today's class.

Exceptional transitive usages are seen in limited contexts in some intransitive verbs. I think this transitive usage of 終わる is limited to "That's it/all (for today)" as a closing word of a lesson/meeting/etc. In such contexts 今日の授業**が**終わります sounds highly unnatural (it sounds the class closes on its own). For other meanings, you have to use ～が終わる or ～を終える following the general rule above. For example, you cannot say 食事を終わる nor 宿題を終わる. If you want to say "Let's have a party when you have finished with the novel":

> - その小説が終わったら、パーティーを開きましょう。: OK
> - その小説を終えたら、パーティーを開きましょう。: OK
> - [×] その小説を終わったら、パーティーを開きましょう。: ungrammatical

There is another exception regarding 終わる; when this is used as an auxiliary verb (i.e., when it follows a stem of another verb and forms a compound verb that means "finish ～ing"), `verb + 終わる` works as a both transitive-and-intransitive verb. In this case, を and が are interchangeable.

> - その小説**を**書き終わったら、パーティーを開きましょう。: OK
> - その小説**が**書き終わったら、パーティーを開きましょう。: OK
> - その小説**を**書き終えたら、パーティーを開きましょう。: OK

See also:

- [In what contexts can "始{はじ}める" be an intransitive verb?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28919/5010)

Comment: 「終わる」に限らず将棋でも「飛車を成る」とか「玉を上がる」とかいいますよ。what's the exact meaning ? って言われても困るけど。

Comment: ああ、「特殊」「珍しい」くらいの気持ちでspecificと書いたのですが確かにこれだと誤解招くんですかね、直します